# Hiding shell output from subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, sh

I am retrieving information about my wireless connection by using

```
In [4]: subprocess.check_output('iwconfig')
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

Out[4]: 'wlan0 ...'
```

I get the string that I want, but I would like to clean the shell from the information about `eth0` and `lo` (notice that these lines are not in the `check_ouput` return string, they are printed to the shell between ipython's `In [4]` and `Out [4]`).

My current guess is that these two lines are considered a warning and are not caught by `check_output`. Hoping they output to `stderr` I tried a few variations on

```
iwconfig > /dev/null 2>&1  # empties my wanted string
iwconfig 2 > /dev/null     # throws an error
```

but without success so far.

How can I prevent the `check_output` from outputting anything to the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `stderr` as your `stdout`:

```
subprocess.check_output('iwconfig', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

If what you want is just to wipe out your `stderr`:

```
import os
subprocess.check_output('iwconfig', stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
```